# How to change the background of a wxPython StyledTextCtrl Margin

Tags: wxpython

I found `SetMarginBackground` ... but unable to use it... I am new to `wxPython`. I need to use it in a `StyledTextCtrl` class which I have created... thanks in advance...

these below codes works fine with fold Margin...

```
self.SetFoldMarginHiColour(True, "#282828")

self.SetFoldMarginColour(True, "#282828")
```

I need to change the Margin background color too...
Kindly help me out.. thanks..

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example?

Answer (score 0):

> wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl is a 1 to 1 mapping of “raw” scintilla interface, whose documentation can be found in the Scintilla website (http://www.scintilla.org/).

Changing margin colours in `Scintilla` - "The way it handles margins--especially when it comes to color--is insanely difficult to understand" See: https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/issues/220 for details, explanations and links, courtesy of an exasperated @jacobslusser

Finally, an example I managed to cobble together from numerous sources:

Where `ed` is a `wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl`

```
# line numbers in the margin
ed.SetMarginType(1, stc.STC_MARGIN_NUMBER)
ed.SetMarginWidth(1, 25)
# Background and foreground colours
ed.StyleSetSpec(stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT,'fore:#000000,back:#00A100')
# Line numbers in margin colours
ed.StyleSetSpec(wx.stc.STC_STYLE_LINENUMBER,'fore:#FFFF00,back:#0000AA')
```

[image]

I can only suggest, that you play with it.